# Could classical equipartition theory if not a Maxwell Boltzmann blackbody distribution apply to translucent dark matter?

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, dark-matter

Given Dark Matter is most likely warm but non-radiating are there any classical field channels for it to communicate its inertial mass?